# Doctrine many to many select

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I read the documentation of `Symfony` and `Doctrine`, however I still not able to solve this problem.

I am working with `Symfony2`. The entities are correctly set up.

I have two tables for data:
students, 
groups

I have the mapping table too:
students_group

Let's say I have five groups:
g1,g2,g3,g4,g5

I want to select all students from g1,g2,g3

How can I do this?

Currently I have this code

```
public function filtered($array) {
    /* GET DOCTRINE */
    $repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:StudyGroups');
    $query = $repository->createQueryBuilder('a')
            ->andWhere('a.id IN (:ids)')
            ->setParameter('ids', $array)
            ->getQuery();

    $groups = $query->getResult();
    $students = $groups->getStudents();

    return $students;
}
```

This doesn't work since there's no method getStudents() on groups.
But if I do something like this

```
public function filtered($array) {
    /* GET DOCTRINE */
    $repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:StudyGroups');
    $query = $repository->createQueryBuilder('a')
            ->andWhere('a.id IN (:ids)')
            ->setParameter('ids', $array)
            ->getQuery();

    $groups = $query->getResult();
    $students = array();
    foreach ($groups as $group) {
        $students = $group->getStudents();
    }

    return $students;
}
```

It works, but there's a problem: I just get the students from the last foreach loop.
I was thinking about creating an array, but those are objects and merge was not working as well. Honestly I think there is a more simple method than this, I just couldn't find it. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Since you want students then you should query from students, join the groups and filter for specific groups.  Something like:

```
$repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:Student');
$query = $repository->createQueryBuilder('student')
  ->leftJoin('student.groups','group')
  ->andWhere('group.id IN (:ids)')
  ->setParameter('ids', $groupIds)
  ->getQuery();
$students = $query->getResult();
```

By the way, using single letters as aliases is an evil evil evil practice.